# How to fetch data from database and show in table in kivy+python

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

### list.py

```
import kivy

kivy.require('1.9.0')  # replace with your current kivy version !
import sqlite3 as lite
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.clearcolor = (0, 0.517, 0.705, 1)

Window.size = (500, 330)
from easygui import msgbox


con = lite.connect('demo.db')
con.text_factory = str
cur = con.cursor()

class TestScreen(Screen):
    pass

    def get_user(self):

        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM `user` order by id asc")
        self.rows = cur.fetchall()

        print(self.rows)

class List(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('list.kv')
        return TestScreen().get_user()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    List().run()
```

above code fetch result but i dont know how to list like table

How to retrieve data from database and list in table like

id  Name
1   abc
2   def

When click on row then it show in new window contain text type with edit value.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for RecycleView widget

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The solution is to use [RecycleView](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html) with SelectableButton, SelectableRecycleGridLayout, Popup and TextInput. Please refer to the example below for details.

## Example

### main.py

```
import sqlite3

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ListProperty, StringProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout import RecycleGridLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup


class TextInputPopup(Popup):
    obj = ObjectProperty(None)
    obj_text = StringProperty("")

    def __init__(self, obj, **kwargs):
        super(TextInputPopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.obj = obj
        self.obj_text = obj.text


class SelectableRecycleGridLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                  RecycleGridLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''


class SelectableButton(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Button):
    ''' Add selection support to the Button '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableButton, self).refresh_view_attrs(rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableButton, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected

    def on_press(self):
        popup = TextInputPopup(self)
        popup.open()

    def update_changes(self, txt):
        self.text = txt


class RV(BoxLayout):
    data_items = ListProperty([])

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.get_users()

    def get_users(self):
        connection = sqlite3.connect("demo.db")
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Users ORDER BY UserID ASC")
        rows = cursor.fetchall()

        # create data_items
        for row in rows:
            for col in row:
                self.data_items.append(col)


class TestApp(App):
    title = "Kivy RecycleView & SQLite3 Demo"

    def build(self):
        return RV()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<TextInputPopup>:
    title: "Popup"
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 400
    auto_dismiss: False

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        TextInput:
            id: txtinput
            text: root.obj_text
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            text: "Save Changes"
            on_release:
                root.obj.update_changes(txtinput.text)
                root.dismiss()
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            text: "Cancel Changes"
            on_release: root.dismiss()


<SelectableButton>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.0, 0.9, .1, .3) if self.selected else (0, 0, 0, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<RV>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        GridLayout:
            size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 25
            cols: 2

            Label:
                text: "User ID"
            Label:
                text: "User Name"

        BoxLayout:
            RecycleView:
                viewclass: 'SelectableButton'
                data: [{'text': str(x)} for x in root.data_items]
                SelectableRecycleGridLayout:
                    cols: 2
                    default_size: None, dp(26)
                    default_size_hint: 1, None
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    multiselect: True
                    touch_multiselect: True
```

### Output

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: for more info visit [RecycleView widget](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use [RecycleView](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html) with SelectableButton, SelectableRecycleGridLayout, Popup and TextInput. Please refer to the example below for details.

to Avoid **Blank screen** Add these two lines in main.py if you use a separate **.kv file**

**Main.py**

```
import sqlite3

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ListProperty, StringProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout import RecycleGridLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
# Add these two lines to your code if you use separate .kv file
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
Builder.load_file('kivy StactOverflow.kv')


class TextInputPopup(Popup):
    obj = ObjectProperty(None)
    obj_text = StringProperty("")

    def __init__(self, obj, **kwargs):
        super(TextInputPopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.obj = obj
        self.obj_text = obj.text


class SelectableRecycleGridLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                  RecycleGridLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''


class SelectableButton(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Button):
    ''' Add selection support to the Button '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableButton, self).refresh_view_attrs(rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableButton, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected

    def on_press(self):
        popup = TextInputPopup(self)
        popup.open()

    def update_changes(self, txt):
        self.text = txt


class RV(BoxLayout):
    data_items = ListProperty([])

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.get_users()

    def get_users(self):
        connection = sqlite3.connect("demo.db")
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Users ORDER BY UserID ASC")
        rows = cursor.fetchall()

        # create data_items
        for row in rows:
            for col in row:
                self.data_items.append(col)


class TestApp(App):
    title = "Kivy RecycleView & SQLite3 Demo"

    def build(self):
        return RV()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

**test.kv**

```
#:it will work kivy 1.10.0 and above

<TextInputPopup>:
    title: "Popup"
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 400
    auto_dismiss: False

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        TextInput:
            id: txtinput
            text: root.obj_text
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            text: "Save Changes"
            on_release:
                root.obj.update_changes(txtinput.text)
                root.dismiss()
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            text: "Cancel Changes"
            on_release: root.dismiss()


<SelectableButton>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.0, 0.9, .1, .3) if self.selected else (0, 0, 0, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<RV>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        GridLayout:
            size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 25
            cols: 2

            Label:
                text: "User ID"
            Label:
                text: "User Name"

        BoxLayout:
            RecycleView:
                viewclass: 'SelectableButton'
                data: [{'text': str(x)} for x in root.data_items]
                SelectableRecycleGridLayout:
                    cols: 2
                    default_size: None, dp(26)
                    default_size_hint: 1, None
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    multiselect: True
                    touch_multiselect: True
```

**Output**
[Fetched from database to frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZj5S.png)