# Display data from a database in a table in kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I referred from ikolim's answer here: [How to fetch data from database and show in table in kivy+python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47013527/how-to-fetch-data-from-database-and-show-in-table-in-kivypython)

But what I want is just like this:

[image: intended output]

I tried editing the code from the answer to get it but it does not seem to work.
Thanks :)

Comment: Why don't you check out the GridLayout?

Comment: @Jezreel.Martin: With reference to the sketch of two buttons in one column, where do you want to see this i.e. in the RecycleView or Popup?

Comment: just a view. So basically, it is a one column that are composed of buttons