# show image on RecycleView

Tags: python, kivy, recyclerview-layout

I try to make a table with data from a SQL DB and images not from a DB. I have tried several things but the image don't show up.

I used this code and modified it: [Link to Stackoverflow Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47013527/how-to-fetch-data-from-database-and-show-in-table-in-kivypython)

**Code snippets that i Changed in Main.py**

```
import sqlite3

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ListProperty, StringProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout import RecycleGridLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.image import Image #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< new
```

[...]

```
class RV(BoxLayout):
    data_items = ListProperty([])
    image = Image(source='image.gif') #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< new

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.get_users()

    def get_users(self):
        connection = sqlite3.connect("demo.db")
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Users ORDER BY UserID ASC")
        rows = cursor.fetchall()

        # create data_items
        for row in rows:
            for col in row:
                self.data_items.append(col)
                print(type(col))
            self.data_items.append(self.image) #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< new
```

[...]

**test.kv**

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<TextInputPopup>:
    title: "Popup"
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 400
    auto_dismiss: False

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        TextInput:
            id: txtinput
            text: root.obj_text
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            text: "Save Changes"
            on_release:
                root.obj.update_changes(txtinput.text)
                root.dismiss()
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            text: "Cancel Changes"
            on_release: root.dismiss()


<SelectableButton>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.0, 0.9, .1, .3) if self.selected else (0, 0, 0, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<RV>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        GridLayout:
            size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 25
            cols: 3

            Label:
                text: "User ID"
            Label:
                text: "User Name"

            Label:
                text: "Image To Insert"

        BoxLayout:
            RecycleView:
                viewclass: 'SelectableButton'
                data: [{'text': str(x)} for x in root.data_items] #<<<<<<<<<< Problem?
                SelectableRecycleGridLayout:
                    cols: 3
                    default_size: None, dp(26)
                    default_size_hint: 1, None
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    multiselect: True
                    touch_multiselect: True
```

**Problem:**

Link that shows a Picture of my problem

[image]

Comment: What is the name of the fields in your table?

Comment: @eyllanesc Table is: Users. Row 1 is 'UserID'-  Integer (1, 2, 3) and Row 2 is 'Name' - Text (derik, dodo, dummi) and Row 3 isn't in the Database. Its in the python file in a for loop to create a empty field in the RecycleView