# Listing Order Numbers, Items and Subitems from database

Tags: python, mysql, listview, kivy, checkboxlist

So, I'm trying to create a list that pulls from a mysql database that displays an order # as a button and a new window expands to display the order numbers items/subitems with checkboxes to have checked when an item is selected.  I have the window to pop up; however, nothing populates and my query prints out information/list.  After all boxes are checked and a Finish button is clicked on, it will remove the order from the list to show it has been worked on.  I found this on the forums; however, it's not pulling anything for me:
[How to fetch data from database and show in table in kivy+python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47013527/how-to-fetch-data-from-database-and-show-in-table-in-kivypython)

Thank you!

main.py

```
import pymysql

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ListProperty, StringProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout import RecycleGridLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

orderNum = "1"

class TextInputPopup(Popup):
    obj = ObjectProperty(None)
    obj_text = StringProperty("")

    def __init__(self, obj, **kwargs):
        super(TextInputPopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.obj = obj
        self.obj_text = obj.text


class SelectableRecycleGridLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                  RecycleGridLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''


class SelectableButton(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Button):
    ''' Add selection support to the Button '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableButton, self).refresh_view_attrs(rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableButton, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected

    def on_press(self):
        popup = TextInputPopup(self)
        popup.open()

    def update_changes(self, txt):
        self.text = txt


class RV(BoxLayout):
    data_items = ListProperty([])

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.get_order()

    def get_order(self):
        connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root',passwd='password', db='Shop')
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        cursor.execute("SELECT itemName, ITEM  FROM order_list WHERE orderID=%s", (orderNum,))
        rows = cursor.fetchall()


        # create data_items
        for row in rows:
            for col in row:
                self.data_items.append(col)


class TestApp(App):
    title = "Kivy RecycleView & pymysql Demo"

    def build(self):
        return RV()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

kivy.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<TextInputPopup>:
    title: "Popup"
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 400
    auto_dismiss: False

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        TextInput:
            id: txtinput
            text: root.obj_text
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            text: "Finish"
            on_release:
                root.obj.update_changes(txtinput.text)
                root.dismiss()
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            text: "Cancel Changes"
            on_release: root.dismiss()


<SelectableButton>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.0, 0.9, .1, .3) if self.selected else (0, 0, 0, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<RV>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        GridLayout:
            size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 25
            cols: 2

            Label:
                text: "Order Number"

        BoxLayout:
            RecycleView:
                viewclass: 'SelectableButton'
                data: [{'text': str(x)} for x in root.data_items]
                SelectableRecycleGridLayout:
                    cols: 2
                    default_size: None, dp(26)
                    default_size_hint: 1, None
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    multiselect: True
                    touch_multiselect: True
```

Here's my list that pulls information and uses a print function:
('Sub', 'Italian')
('Sub', 'Meatball')
('Drink', 'Apple Juice')
('Side', 'Salad')
('Soup', 'Chicken and rice')

[What I have and What I'm Trying to Achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMOu1.png)