# How to edit SQLite database values using kivy and RecycleView

Tags: python, sqlite, kivy

I'm trying to display an sqlite3 database in python using kivy. Tested out ikolim's solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47013527/how-to-fetch-data-from-database-and-show-in-table-in-kivypython#_=_) and it works as intended in displaying the database contents into the RecycleView's button labels:

[image]

And when a button is pressed, a popup and edit function appears as intended:

[image]

And it does edit the selected button's text as shown in the next screenshot.. :

[image]

..but not the sqlite database values. **Would it be possible to reflect the changes the user makes inside the Kivy app to the values inside the sqlite database?**

Here are the codes:

### test.py

```
import sqlite3

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ListProperty, StringProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout import RecycleGridLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

connection = sqlite3.connect("demo.db", isolation_level=None)
cursor = connection.cursor()

class TextInputPopup(Popup):
    obj = ObjectProperty(None)
    obj_text = StringProperty("")

    def __init__(self, obj, **kwargs):
        super(TextInputPopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.obj = obj
        self.obj_text = obj.text


class SelectableRecycleGridLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                  RecycleGridLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''


class SelectableButton(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Button):
    ''' Add selection support to the Button '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableButton, self).refresh_view_attrs(rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableButton, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected

    def on_press(self):
        popup = TextInputPopup(self)
        popup.open()

    def update_changes(self, txt):
        self.text = txt


class RV(BoxLayout):
    data_items = ListProperty([])

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.get_users()

    def get_users(self):

        cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Callbacks(cName TEXT, cID INT, cbTime INT, cbRems TEXT)")
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Callbacks VALUES ('Client1','1','1500','Test1')")
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Callbacks VALUES ('Client2','2','1600','Test2')")
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Callbacks VALUES ('Client3','3','1700','Test3')")
        connection.commit()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Callbacks ORDER BY ROWID DESC")

        rows = cursor.fetchall()

        # create data_items
        for row in rows:
            for col in row:
                self.data_items.append(col)

        for row in rows:
            print(self.data_items)



class TestApp(App):
    title = "Kivy RecycleView & SQLite3 Demo"

    def build(self):
        return RV()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<TextInputPopup>:
    title: "Popup"
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 400
    auto_dismiss: False

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        TextInput:
            id: txtinput
            text: root.obj_text
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            text: "Save Changes"
            on_release:
                root.obj.update_changes(txtinput.text)
                root.dismiss()
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            text: "Cancel Changes"
            on_release: root.dismiss()


<SelectableButton>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.0, 0.9, .1, .3) if self.selected else (0, 0, 0, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<RV>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        GridLayout:
            size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 25
            cols: 4

            Label:
                text: "Name"
            Label:
                text: "ID"
            Label:
                text: "CB Time"
            Label:
                text: "Remarks"

        BoxLayout:
            RecycleView:
                viewclass: 'SelectableButton'
                data: [{'text': str(x)} for x in root.data_items]
                SelectableRecycleGridLayout:
                    cols: 4
                    default_size: None, dp(26)
                    default_size_hint: 1, None
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    multiselect: True
                    touch_multiselect: True
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to reflect the changes to the `sql`, you'll need to use the `update` command to update the `sql` table.